# Preposición + sujeto + infinitivo

Tags: gramática, infinitivo

¿Usan ustedes, o se usan en sus dialectos, expresiones del tipo **preposición + sujeto + infinitivo** (donde la preposición es generalmente *de* o *para*)? ¿Qué reglas siguen? Acabo de ver una referencia a este fenómeno en una respuesta, al pasar, y me sorprendió que no se hubiese tratado el tema. Estoy hablando de frases como las siguientes:

- *Necesito que me avises **para yo saber** a qué hora esperarte.*
- ***Para ellos aprenderlo*** bien van a tener que practicar.
- *Antes **de ella decidirse** lo pensó mucho.*
- *Esto se hizo **sin nosotros tener** ninguna idea de lo que pasaba.*
- ***Al llegar ustedes*** al lugar, ¿qué vieron?

Hay publicado un [estudio](http://www.biblioteca.org.ar/libros/156354.pdf) de este fenómeno y sus variantes (con otras preposiciones, con sujetos pronominales y no, con sujeto pospuesto o prepuesto al infinitivo...) pero se trata de un único trabajo; en foros de castellano predominan opiniones prescriptivistas no informadas que simplemente consideran que estas construcciones "están mal".

En portugués existe el infinitivo personal, hoy muchas veces simplificado de manera que se ve exactamente como estas construcciones en castellano. Su uso es muy frecuente en ocasiones en que un hispanohablante usaría en su lugar el subjuntivo en una subordinada (*"[Não espere **eu ir embora** pra perceber](https://www.letras.com/pitty/1507865/)"* = "No esperes **que yo me vaya** para darte cuenta"). Pero no sé si nuestro infinitivo con sujeto es asimilable a esto, y claramente su uso admitido no es tan amplio.

Comment: Sí la he oído en España. Es algo barroca, pero se usa. La primera me sonaría mejor como _Necesito que me avises para que yo sepa..._.

Comment: Se usa, pero en España al menos jamás se haría explícito un pronombre como sujeto salvo que hubiera muchísima ambigüedad.

Comment: Se usa en México.  A mí me gusta esta construcción.

Answer (score 3):

Yo mismo las he usado alguna vez.
No es que sea una respuesta autoritativa, pero poco más te puedo decir.

Más allá de que a alguien le pueda chocar que se coloque el pronombre antes del verbo, no se me ocurre en qué manera podría estar mal una construcción así.

> - Necesito que me des el martillo para sacar el clavo.
> - Necesito que me des el martillo para sacar el clavo yo.
> - Necesito que me des el martillo para sacar yo el clavo.
> - Necesito que me des el martillo para yo sacar el clavo.

Sobre el uso de una subordinada en su lugar: hombre... Correcto también es, eso está claro, y además se puede aplicar en todos los casos manteniendo la misma estructura:

> - Necesito que me des el martillo para que saque el clavo.
> - Necesito que me des el martillo para que saque el clavo yo.
> - Necesito que me des el martillo para que saque yo el clavo.
> - Necesito que me des el martillo para que yo saque el clavo.

¿Es más frecuente? Supongo que dependerá de la zona, como siempre.
¿Suena mejor? Eso ya es cuestión de gustos y de a lo que esté acostumbrado cada uno.
¿Es más correcto? En mi opinión, son igual de correctas ambas formas.

Comment: Cuando hablaba de subordinadas me refería a algo así: *para yo saber* = *para que yo sepa*. Se nota más cuando no hay co-referencia y el pronombre se vuelve obligatorio: *Esto se hizo sin nosotros tener idea* no funciona sin el *nosotros*.

Comment: La NGE habla de ello pero si no me recuerdo mal (estoy de viaje y de momento no puedo consultarla bien) dice que es una estructura perfectamente válida, no obstante, resulta rarísima e incluso agramatical para algunos hablantes en ciertas zonas.  (Yo tuve que buscarlo hace un tiempo para defenderme cuando alguien me dijo que la estructura era errada).